# What would cause a file to disappear in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, filesystems

When I copy a specific file from a share to a local computer it disappeared almost immediately.   I have hidden files turned off, so that isn’t it; I don’t see any threat detected  in the virus scanners, and I even tried copying it into a zip file first; copying the zip file over first and then extracting it and it still disappears.

I also tried this on various machines and it disappears, I’m really at a loss as to why it happens or what to do, but my installer won’t work without it; it’s a cab file.

I also tried restoring the file by downloading it from the backup server and the download fails.

Comment: What's the name of the file?

Comment: Where are you copying the file, from location, to location ?   If trying to copy into a secure location, the copy can fail so it seems to "disappear" .

Comment: @Aenfa inavnet.cab

Comment: @John In ‘%USERPROFILE%\Documents\New Folder (2)\’

Comment: If it is your USER it should not be an issue. If some other user, it is secured. Installers normally work from the USER installing the program.

Comment: So I was copying via RDP from my domain admin account to my regular user account.   So instead I tried using UNC to copy it to the domain users account from the domain user account on the file server but it still disappears.

Comment: It could be that Windows Defender or whichever antivirus software you have is silently deleting/quarantining the file. Try temporarily turning off real-time protection and see if it still disappears. Also check the protection history and see if there's anything there.

Comment: run Process Monitor, it should reveal the process removing the file.

Comment: @HelpingHand Hey that Process Monitor did the trick!  It was Cisco AMP antivirus that was causing the issue thank you!